# On mysql What is the Regexp to replace contents with enclosed square brackets?

Tags: mysql, regex

Example Statement: [userid:30]  is an administrator.[editor:67] is an administrator.

I need to replace [userid:30] and [editor:67] in above statement.

Comment: On which language exactly? Don't do tag spamming please.

Comment: Actually I am using regex in mysql user defined function

Comment: Because no one will know yet what user defined function you're using, no one can tell you, what the syntax for this regexp will be.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct support for regex replacements in MySQL. However, you can use it with a function like [this regex_replace](http://techras.wordpress.com/2011/06/02/regex-replace-for-mysql/) together with this regex `\[[^\]]+\]`, like so:

```
SELECT regex_replace('\[[^\]]+\]','',sometextfield)
```

Comment: Thanks for ur reply . But sorry  above regex not working for this **select regex_replace('\[[^\]+\]','','2my test3_text-to. Welcome to RegExr v2.0 ![user_id:39]');**

Comment: Sorry, small typo, fixed (see the match in [the regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/nJ8cJ8/51))

Comment: I've checked with same on above link **\[[^\]]+\]** but that also not working

Comment: Could u please test in mysql console. I've checked but for the above patterns not working

Comment: You have to use the function to which I provided a link. It's a user-defined function, not part of standard MySQL syntax.